# Who dies in A Death In The Gunj?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, a-death-in-the-gunj

A Death In The Gunj shows a family who's come down on holidays in a remote town in India.

The opening scene of the movie is a shot of any implied dead body in the trunk of a car, which is being ridden by Nandu, Brian & Shutu.

The climax of the movie shows

> Shutu holding a gun, in a mentally unstable position and backed into a tree trunk corner, pointing it at Vikram, who's been tormenting him the entire trip. But later, Shutu points the gun at his chin.

The gun is fired offscreen and blood splatters on the tree behind. The last scene of the movie is the first scene with the 3 people in the car with a dead body in the trunk.

So, who dies in A Death In The Gunj?

Answer (score 2):

It's late to answer this,

The last moment makes us think wider because someone was killed but who is it, Shutu or Vikram?

We are thinking Shutu was not killed because Shutu was in the back seat of the car when Nandu was driving the car, and Brian was beside him after taking the dead body in dicky.

As per my thinking, if Vikram was shot then he would not get his blood on his own face, and there was lots of blood on the tree as well, so I don't think that much blood would flow back to the gun side.

The above arguments make me accept that,

> Shutu was killed. Also [Konkona Sen Sharma (director) clarifies later who actually died](https://www.newsbytesapp.com/news/entertainment/interesting-facts-on-a-death-in-the-gunj/story#:%7E:text=Sen%20Sharma%20clarifies%20later%20who%20actually%20died%20in%20%27Gunj%27&text=But%20it%20was%20the%20last,car%20was%20a%20%22ghost.%22), "Shutu did die, and the one in the car was a ghost."

And also written in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Death_in_the_Gunj) as well,

> The movie ends with the beginning scene in which Nandu and Brian drive away with Shutu's dead body in the trunk with the ghost of Shutu in the backseat. The closing credits show the road behind the moving car from this ghost's perspective.